# ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hmset' command

Tags: node.js, redis, coffeescript

I have the following code:

```
setOnOrder = (map) ->
  console.log map
  if _.isEmpty map
    Promise.resolve()
  else
    hmsetPr "onorder.tmp", map

onOrder = (req, res, next) ->
  console.log req.query
  if req.query.syncStart
    delPr "onorder.tmp"
      .then -> sendOK(res)
      .catch next
  else if req.query.syncComplete
    renamePr("onorder.tmp", "onorder")
      .then -> sendOK(res)
      .catch next
  else
    onOrderMap = _(req.body)
      .groupBy( (r) -> r.sku )
      .mapValues( (v) -> JSON.stringify(v) )
      .value()
    console.log "sync.onorder #{_.size(onOrderMap)} skus"
    setOnOrder onOrderMap
      .then -> sendOK(res)
      .catch next
```

where `map` is like:

```
{ 'N52Z-LH1': '[{"doCref":"E3320","doAccount":"EVE001","sku":"N52Z-LH1","crDate":"20150703","crTime":"09:52:52","reqQty":150,"recQty":0,"reqDate":"20150703","recDate":"","cmpLtd":"F"}]',
  'N52Z-LH2': '[{"doCref":"E3320","doAccount":"EVE001","sku":"N52Z-LH2","crDate":"20150703","crTime":"09:52:52","reqQty":150,"recQty":0,"reqDate":"20150703","recDate":"","cmpLtd":"F"}]',
  'N52Z-LH3': '[{"doCref":"E3320","doAccount":"EVE001","sku":"N52Z-LH3","crDate":"20150703","crTime":"09:52:52","reqQty":150,"recQty":0,"reqDate":"20150703","recDate":"","cmpLtd":"F"}]',
  'N54Z-BL1': '[{"doCref":"E3320","doAccount":"EVE001","sku":"N54Z-BL1","crDate":"20150703","crTime":"09:52:52","reqQty":100,"recQty":0,"reqDate":"20150703","recDate":"","cmpLtd":"F"}]',
  'SA01-MGR1': '[{"doCref":"E3321","doAccount":"ARM001","sku":"SA01-MGR1","crDate":"20150703","crTime":"15:47:52","reqQty":160,"recQty":0,"reqDate":"20150703","recDate":"","cmpLtd":"F"}]',
  'SA01-MGR2': '[{"doCref":"E3321","doAccount":"ARM001","sku":"SA01-MGR2","crDate":"20150703","crTime":"15:47:52","reqQty":320,"recQty":0,"reqDate":"20150703","recDate":"","cmpLtd":"F"}]',
  'SA01-MGR3': '[{"doCref":"E3321","doAccount":"ARM001","sku":"SA01-MGR3","crDate":"20150703","crTime":"15:47:52","reqQty":320,"recQty":0,"reqDate":"20150703","recDate":"","cmpLtd":"F"}]',
  'SA01-MGR4': '[{"doCref":"E3321","doAccount":"ARM001","sku":"SA01-MGR4","crDate":"20150703","crTime":"15:47:52","reqQty":240,"recQty":0,"reqDate":"20150703","recDate":"","cmpLtd":"F"}]',
  'SA01-MGR5': '[{"doCref":"E3321","doAccount":"ARM001","sku":"SA01-MGR5","crDate":"20150703","crTime":"15:47:52","reqQty":80,"recQty":0,"reqDate":"20150703","recDate":"","cmpLtd":"F"}]',
  'SA01-MPL3': '[{"doCref":"E3321","doAccount":"ARM001","sku":"SA01-MPL3","crDate":"20150703","crTime":"15:47:53","reqQty":240,"recQty":0,"reqDate":"20150703","recDate":"","cmpLtd":"F"}]',
  'SA02-MNA1': '[{"doCref":"E3322","doAccount":"ARM001","sku":"SA02-MNA1","crDate":"20150703","crTime":"15:49:59","reqQty":200,"recQty":0,"reqDate":"20150703","recDate":"","cmpLtd":"F"}]',
  'SA02-MNA2': '[{"doCref":"E3322","doAccount":"ARM001","sku":"SA02-MNA2","crDate":"20150703","crTime":"15:49:59","reqQty":300,"recQty":0,"reqDate":"20150703","recDate":"","cmpLtd":"F"}]',
  'SA02-MNA3': '[{"doCref":"E3322","doAccount":"ARM001","sku":"SA02-MNA3","crDate":"20150703","crTime":"15:49:59","reqQty":200,"recQty":0,"reqDate":"20150703","recDate":"","cmpLtd":"F"}]',
  'SA40-MBL5': '[{"doCref":"E3323","doAccount":"ARM001","sku":"SA40-MBL5","crDate":"20150703","crTime":"15:51:46","reqQty":25,"recQty":0,"reqDate":"20150703","recDate":"","cmpLtd":"F"}]',
  'SA40-MNA5': '[{"doCref":"E3323","doAccount":"ARM001","sku":"SA40-MNA5","crDate":"20150703","crTime":"15:51:46","reqQty":25,"recQty":0,"reqDate":"20150703","recDate":"","cmpLtd":"F"}]' }
```

but everytime i try to set it in redis, I get the following traceback:

```
http://localhost:3000/sync/onorder Error: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hmset' command
  at JavascriptReplyParser._parseResult (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/redis/lib/parsers/javascript.js:43:16)
  at JavascriptReplyParser.try_parsing (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/redis/lib/parsers/javascript.js:114:21)
  at JavascriptReplyParser.run (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/redis/lib/parsers/javascript.js:126:22)
  at JavascriptReplyParser.execute (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/redis/lib/parsers/javascript.js:107:10)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/redis/index.js:131:27)
  at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
  at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
From previous event:
  at ret (<anonymous>:8:21)
  at setOnOrder (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/app/controllers/sync.coffee:277:5)
  at onOrder (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/app/controllers/sync.coffee:295:5)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at next (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
  at Route.dispatch (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
  at Function.process_params (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
  at next (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
  at Function.handle (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
  at router (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at trim_prefix (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
  at Function.process_params (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
  at next (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
  at urlencodedParser (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:81:44)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at trim_prefix (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
  at Function.process_params (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
  at next (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:129:5
  at invokeCallback (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)
  at done (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)
  at Gunzip.onEnd (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:308:7)
  at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
  at Gunzip.emit (events.js:166:7)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
  at doNTCallback2 (node.js:441:9)
  at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:396:17)
```

any advise on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I had null values